# Ajax not working with Node js - Express js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax

Im trying to send data from my server side to my client side with ajax but when i use res.send(data) in node, it show me a empty html with the data and i want to get data from my client side without reloading the page and edit something in my actual html

Here's my server-side code

```
    app.post('/',(req,res)=>{
    var userName = req.body.username;
    var password = req.body.password;

    connection.query('SELECT * from admin',(err, rows, fields)=> {
      if (!err){
        if((userName == rows[0].usuario) && (password == rows[0].contraseña)){
            res.sendStatus(200);    

        }else{
            res.send('Incorrect username or password')
        }
      }else{
        res.send('Error while performing Query.');
      }

    });

});
```

Here's my client-side code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#login-form').submit(function (e) {
        setTimeout(function () {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            data: ({username: $('input[name=username]'),password: $('input[name=password]')}),
            success: function(data,textStatus){
                if(textStatus.statusCode == 200) {
                    $('.error-user').html('Succes');    
                }else{
                    $('.error-user').html('Not Success');
                }


            },
        });
        }, 1000);

});       
});
```

**UPDATE: I removed the setTimeOut() but when I submit the form the page freeze like two seconds and then nothing happen, I get this 'error Maximum call stack size exceeded', dont get me data just stay in the same view if like post method was never called**

**UPDATE-FINAL: I got values from input outside of the ajax and it works nice,thanks :#**

Comment: Add an error handler to the Ajax call. It also looks like you are not sending back jsonp

Comment: Why are you using the `setTimeout()`?  It is part of the problem.  Your form has submitted and the page reloaded from the form submission BEFORE you run your ajax call and before you call `e.preventDefauilt()` so that is called too late.  Remove the `setTimeout()` or put the `e.preventDefault()` before the `setTimeout()`.  In either case, the `setTimeout()` seems like screwy code.  If you thought you were fixing something with that, then that's a hack and you should fix whatever it is the proper way and remove the `setTimeout()`.

Comment: look update question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot : `.val()` to send the value of inputs :

```
data: ({username: $('input[name=username]').val(), password: $('input[name=password]').val() }),
```

and NOT :

```
data: ({username: $('input[name=username]'),password: $('input[name=password]')}),
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the setTimeout which is preventing your preventDefault from running in the actual event handler and causing you to see the response in the browser load rather than ajax handler, and debug from there.

Comment: If I do that, the page freeze for a moment and then nothing happen and it give me this error = 'Maximum call stack size exceeded "

Comment: Can you add that info to your question, like complete code and exact error message?  setTimeout is definitely not right.. so call stack is the error to fix

Comment: Show the complete error including stack, it will show the functions that are repeating

Comment: getting this error 

jquery.min.js:4 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Ab (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Ab (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Ab (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Ab (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Ab (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Ab (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Ab (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Ab (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Ab (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Ab (jquery.min.js:4)

Answer (score 0):

Preventdefault is creating issue. You can remove that to run Ajax call

Comment: still take me to another html

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you may be using the  request method.

To retrieve the data from your node server's data you should use the `GET` method when the page completes loading.

To send a request to node when the form is  submitted your often will send a request  from the client side js to make a persistent change to  a database on the node server. Depending on what you would like to achieve, you should use the `POST`, `PUT`, `PATCH`, `DELETE` methods.

These methods will typically create, update, update a portion of data set, or remove records or documents from an SQL or NoSQL database available to your node server.

Comment: I can't use GET method because the information is username and password from user